# which files to write tests in

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

Say I have Class a, that creates instances of Class b. Say Class b is updated from json that is deserialized from a web call.

```
Class A
{
  function onNewJSONMessage(array) {
     for data in array {
       B *b = new B();
       b.updateWithData(b);
       self.myObjects.add(b);
    }
  }
}

Class B {
  function updateWithData(data) {
    // self.prop1 = data.prop1;
    // self.prop2 = data.prop2;
    // self.prop3 = data.prop3;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Ignoring for awhile this pseudo language, and just concentrating on testing, I have two ways I can test this.

1. when subject under test(Class A) gets onNewJSONMessage with one object,

   - self.myObjects has a Class B object that has prop1 == “prop1” \n
   - self.myObjects has a Class B object that has prop2 == “prop2”
   - self.myObjects has a Class B object that has prop3 == “prop3”
   - ...
2. when subject under test(Class B) gets updateWithData with one object

   - self.prop1 == @“prop1”
   - self.prop2 == @“prop2”
   - self.prop3 == @“prop3”
   - …

I like (1) because when I’m developing onNewJSONMessage, I can just punch out the proper lines in updateWithData and be sure that A is creating B objects properly. On the other hand, (2)’s tests are more appropriate because they are local to the subject under test. Which one of these should I use?

If I go with (1), how do I later add tests that are not specific to handling the json message from the server? Say I could update B not only from class A, but class C too.

If I go with (2), how do I make sure that in my method to handle server json, I am calling the proper ‘updateWithData’ call? I heard that testing 'implementation' is not a good thing to do. (It’s hard to test that method gets called on a mock in this case, unless I mock the initialization of B, which is a pain).

Writing both is tedious, not to mention a duplication of tests. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Serialization code belongs somewhere separate from the model itself.
Depending on your platform, you could perhaps use a generic deserializer, tweaked using model annotations. But let's assume you wish to write your own code.

I'd then expect both methods (the one that fills the Bs and the one that creates A and adds the Bs) to be located in a separate class C, whose responsibility it is to deserialize A and B. The C would call the constructor and setter methods in class B and some kind of addB() method in A.
Unit tests for class C belong in a separate class CTest.

How to test this depends a bit on how difficult the deserialization is but a nice way would be to deserialize from JSON to A and B instances and from there back to JSON and check that the result is unchanged.

A bit of an afterthought:
Generally, in cases where code from one class calls code in another class, you can mock the second class to prevent testing the same code twice. But I would not recommend this for model POJO's.